# Fragment transaction show does not show my hidden fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

This should rather be a trivial task but somehow I manage to fail in performing it.

Step 1:

Add the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layFragment, Fragment1.newInstance(), "FragmentTag1").commit();
```

Step 2:

Hide the fragment and add another one. The second one should be visible on screen

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentTag1")).commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layFragment, Fragment2.newInstance()),"FragmentTag2").commit();
```

Step 3:

The second fragment is removed and the first one is shown again

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentTag2")).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentTag1")).commit();
```

Step 1and 2 are working fine. On Step 3, Fragment2 is being removed but Fragment1 is not shown again, even if it currently is hidden.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling Hide & Add  re Remove & Show Just Call :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.

Answer (score 0):

at first time you have to add your fragment,next time onwards replace the fragment with whatever fragment you want.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.details, your fragment instance);
ft.addToBacksStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Could you detail a bit please ?